# Including a link in a facebook Post from the api

Tags: facebook, api

I am using the restfb Java api (from Scala) to post to Facebook. I have two questions.
i) If you put a link in the message field of a post, it will automatically be rendered as a link. But what if you want to include link text instead of the href in the post message? Including Dude gets rendered as a string. But clearly there are many examples of things like "Hey, check out this **car** , where **car** is a link. How do you do this?

ii) Facebook is including the description of my company in each post. I set the description field to the empty String and its still showing up. I even removed the description from the settings page for my Facebook app and its still showing up. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the link in the `message` parameter, you can put it in the `link` parameter of your HTTP POST to the Graph API.  Otherwise, it cannot be done with an inline link that has text (like what you can do with normal href's).

I don't know of a way to remove a description meta tag once it's been set.  Try just a period instead of an empty string to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was hoping to put something else in the link parameter but you are right - Its definitely an option. I tried an empty String for the description and that didn't work. Are you familiar with anything in the newest apis that can accomplish this or even something more flexible?

Comment: sorry, I don't.  Happy coding.